# Setting up service compatible with GeoPy?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geocoding, software-recommendations, geopy

GeoPy is a great tool, but the providers lack data for growing parts of the City that students are moving into, and we can't geocode them accurately because these providers can't update their data as frequently as we need.

The most up-to-date data that we need to geocode with is served up daily by the City and County of Denver in the form of address points, parcels, and street centerlines.

Is there any documentation or examples of creating a service that can talk to GeoPy that is based on the datasets I've described above?

On our end, we can update data from the City on a daily basis into a PostGIS database and publish it via GeoServer through the various formats available to an internal (or external?) service.

From there our automated GeoPy scripts can keep our student (and more) address points accurate to the City's data.

Other local options include the PostGIS Geocoder (TIGER data won't work), MMQGIS on street centerlines (can't automate, and would prefer to use parcel or point datasets), and of course we're looking for something non-proprietary as even that solution wasn't working for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the short term, we have decided that the Mapzen / Pelias Geocoder, which sources from OpenAddresses.io, which sources from the City and County of Denver Address Points:

https://github.com/openaddresses/openaddresses/blob/master/sources/us/co/denver.json

Comment: mapzen will be shut downd shortly http://www.govtech.com/biz/GIS-Company-Mapzen-to-Shut-Down-but-Users-Can-Still-Grab-the-Open-Source-Code-and-Data.html

Comment: @Geo.Dude yes, sad, and I put a bounty on this question after learning that. Unfortunately we're looking to another source (paid) so we're likely to abandon the effort of using a FOSS4G geocoder entirely, since there STILL isn't one!

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with a package called zpy4, (look for it on bitbucket)  it's a wrapper for the zp4 geocoding service which uses the U.S. Postal Service's Ribbs database(updated monthly).

I've found the data quality to be a lot better than any other geocoding service, but it takes some work to get set up and there's not a ton of documentation